# Can't seem to figure out how this works

Tags: winapi, assembly, x86

I'm trying to determine the password in this challenge code, but can't figure out how it works. Does anyone have some tips on how to go about figuring out what it does?

```
.text:00401000                 public start
.text:00401000 start:
.text:00401000                 mov     esi, offset loc_401013
.text:00401005
.text:00401005 loc_401005:                             ; CODE XREF: .text:00401011j
.text:00401005                 cmp     esi, offset byte_40105F
.text:0040100B                 jz      short loc_401013
.text:0040100D                 xor     byte ptr [esi], 0CDh
.text:00401010                 inc     esi
.text:00401011                 jmp     short loc_401005
.text:00401013 ; ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
.text:00401013
.text:00401013 loc_401013:                             ; CODE XREF: .text:0040100Bj
.text:00401013                                         ; DATA XREF: .text:starto
.text:00401013                 xor     bl, al
.text:00401015                 test    eax, 44CD8DFDh
.text:0040101A                 or      eax, edx
.text:0040101C                 jnp     short near ptr 400FE1h
.text:0040101E                 db      2Eh
.text:0040101E                 into
.text:00401020                 mov     esp, [esi]
.text:00401022                 xor     eax, 9936B34Ch
.text:00401027                 mov     edi, 0DBB8A8B8h
.text:0040102C                 cmpsd
.text:0040102D                 int     0A5h            ; used by BASIC while in interpreter
.text:0040102F                 sub     ebp, 0CDA5CD8Dh
.text:00401035                 in      eax, dx
.text:00401035 ; ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
.text:00401036                 dw 0CD8Dh
.text:00401038                 dd 0D832CDA7h, 0CD8DFD55h, 0CDA7D926h, 8DED81A5h, 0EDEDA5CDh
.text:00401038                 dd 0CDA7CD8Dh, 0FD55D832h, 0CDA7CD8Dh, 0FDA5D832h
.text:0040105C                 db 8Dh, 0CDh, 0Eh
.text:0040105F byte_40105F     db 0EEh                 ; DATA XREF: .text:loc_401005o
.text:00401060                 dd 90EEEEEEh, 90h, 66h dup(0)
```

Comment: This question (especially with its vague title) is unlikely to be useful to future visitors to the site. Have you tried debugging it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code simply XORs each byte from `loc_401013:` to `byte_40105F` with 0xCD, then jumps to the start of that code, which makes your disassembly meaningless. To see what the code is doing, you'd need to XOR each byte in that range with 0xCD and re-disassemble it.